# PAM must prohibit the use of cached authentications after one day

Tags: login

**Issue:**

Ubuntu 16.04 Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) must prohibit the use of cached authentications after one day.

**Suggested Fix:**

per NIST -> "Configure Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) to prohibit the use of cached authentications after one day.

Add or change the following line in "/etc/pam.d/common-auth" or "/etc/pam.d/common-session" just below the line "[pam]".

timestamp_timeout = 86400"

**My Problem:**

Where do I place 'timestamp_timeout = 86400' ? I placed it in the file at the bottom of the /etc/pam.d/common-auth and it broke cron.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ubuntu Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_timestamp.8.html), the timestamp_timeout param is an optional argument that can be added to the pam_timestamp.so module.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_timestamp.8.html